# PHP simple foreach loop with HTML

Tags: php, html, foreach

I am wondering if it will work best to actually write the following for example:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($array as $key=>$value){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

So basically embedding HTML inside foreach loop but without using `echo` to print the table tags. Will this work? I know in JSP this works.

Comment: The [alternative control syntax](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) might be even better, YMMV.

Comment: Maybe he has to pay for executing his code :).

Comment: It's not a useless question. This particular implementation is difficult to find in the PHP docs, and the accepted answer provides validation that it works without ten thousand developers needing to "just create a sample array and try" on an individual basis.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

This will work although when embedding PHP in HTML it is better practice to use the following form:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($array as $key=>$value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $key; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

You can find the doc for [the alternative syntax on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: or alternative instead of echo $key, you can use <td><?=$key?></td>