# Join Query Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to join two tables in codeigniter. I have two tables called **designation** and **staff**. I have created to select staff title using dropdown, but this shows data in data table using foreign key value. Now I want show the title in designation table instead of foreign key value. Please any one can help me?

### **Controller**

```
 public function index()
{  

    $data['designation'] = $this->staff_model->get_designation();

    $this->load->view('admin_include/header');
    $this->load->view('admin_pages/staff_list',$data);
}

    public function fillgrid(){
        $this->staff_model->fillgrid();
    }
```

### **Model**

```
class Staff_model extends CI_Model {

//get designation table to populate the designation dropdown
function get_designation()     
{ 
    $this->db->select('designation_id');
    $this->db->select('title');
    $this->db->from('designation');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    $designation_id = array('-SELECT-');
    $title = array('-SELECT-');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
    {
        array_push($designation_id, $result[$i]->designation_id);
        array_push($title, $result[$i]->title);
    }
    return $designation_result = array_combine($designation_id, $title);
}


public function fillgrid(){
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
    $data = $this->db->get('staff');

    foreach ($data->result() as $row){
        $edit = base_url().'index.php/staff_controller/edit/';
        $delete = base_url().'index.php/staff_controller/delete/';
        echo "<tr>
                    <td>$row->first_name</td>
                    <td>$row->last_name</td> 
                    <td>$row->designation_id</td>
                    <td>$row->email</td>
                    <td>$row->address</td>
                    <td>$row->contact_no</td>
                    <td>$row->work_experience</td>    
                    <td>$row->qualifications</td>    
                    <td>$row->created</td>
                    <td><a href='$edit' data-id='$row->id' class='btnedit' title='edit'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' title='edit'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='$delete' data-id='$row->id' class='btndelete' title='delete'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></a></td>    
                </tr>";

    }
    exit;
}
```

### **View**

```
 <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="frmadd" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/staff_controller/create" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="first_name">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="last_name">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>


             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="title">Title</label>
                <?php
            $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "designation"';
            echo form_dropdown('designation',$designation, set_value('designation'), $attributes);?>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="contact_no">Contact</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_no" id="contact_no" placeholder="contact number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="work_experience">Work Experience</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="work_experience" id="work_experience" placeholder="Work Experience">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="qualifications">Qualifications</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="qualifications" id="qualifications" placeholder="Qualifications">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="nic">NIC</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nic" id="nic" placeholder="NIC">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn btn-success" value="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Email</th><th>Address</th><th>Contact</th><th>Work Experience</th><th>Qualifications</th><th>created</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody id="fillgrid">

        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Writing html code inside the model is a bit dirty.

Comment: Post your table structure.
Also if you want to join staff and designation table, you will do this assuming of your table structure. 
`Select s.*, d.position from staff s on designation d on d.id = s.designationid`

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables like this:

```
$data = $this->db->select('*')->from('staff')
  ->join('designation', 'staff.designation_id = designation.designation_id');
  ->order_by("id", "desc")->get();
$result = $data->result(); // every result now has 'title'
```

Also I would strongly recommend to remove the "echo html" thing from your model and just return an array. You can do whatever you like inside the view. Take a look at this: [PHP simple foreach loop with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258345/php-simple-foreach-loop-with-html)

Comment: inside fillgrid function. Of course after removing the first 2 lines as they are shown here.

Comment: Also, It's really nice being kind but saying "please help me" all the time won't take you very far, neither will help you in the long run. First you need to understand the code you're using before asking any help.