# HTML in for loop with variable

Tags: php, html, wordpress, variables, for-loop

I was wondering if it was possible to use HTML inside a for loop while using a variable.

So this works at the moment:

```
<?php
[...]

for ($x=0 ; $x <= $nr_of_bookitems; $x +=2) {
    echo get_book($x)->meta_value;
}

[...]
?>
```

But this doesn't give me the result I want, because I want it to be urls.

So I want it like this:

```
<?php
[...]

for ($x=0 ; $x <= $nr_of_bookitems; $x +=2) {
    <a href="<?php echo get_book($x)->meta_value;; ?>" target="_blank">Text</a>
}

[...]
?>
```

But this doesn't work because I haven't close the php tags and HTML doesn't do anything. But when I close the php tags, it seems I can't use the variable $x anymore:

```
<?php
[...]

for ($x=0 ; $x <= $nr_of_bookitems; $x +=2) ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_book($x)->meta_value;; ?>" target="_blank">Text</a>

<?php 
}

[...]
?>
```

I couldn't find a solution on the internet. I do have seen some examples with foreach [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258345/php-simple-foreach-loop-with-html), but i'm not sure how to use that in this case if even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($x=0 ; $x <= $nr_of_bookitems; $x +=2)
{
    $meta_value = get_book($x)->meta_value;
    echo '<a href="' . $meta_value . '" target="_blank">Text</a>';
}
```

Comment: You just made me really happy. Sometimes the solutions are much easier than I think they are.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
for ($x=0 ; $x <= $nr_of_bookitems; $x +=2)
{
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_book($x)->meta_value;; ?>" target="_blank">Text</a>
    <?php 
}
```

I think the only problem was you left off the opening curly bracket.