# foreach loop inside variable

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Here is a situation I need to display values from array through foreach loop inside variable and than echo that variable inside  HTML table. Thanks in Advance. . I have checked all related links in stackoverflow  some links are given  below.

[PHP  simple foreach loop with HTML [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258345/php-simple-foreach-loop-with-html)

My  question is about store looping array inside a variable.. And their is no similarity in another and my question

I want my output to be this way below
[image: Output link]

I'm getting this error image given below
[image: Error image link here]

php filename: foreachloop.php

```
    <?php
$arr = array("Apple","orange","strawberry");
$abc = '<table border="2">
            <tr>
                <th>Names</th>
            </tr>
            foreach($arr as $key){
            <tr>
                <td>'.$key.'</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>';

echo $abc;
?>
```

Comment: it is clear in your error message.

Comment: i'm unable to figure it out because foreach loop is inside variable and i  want the same way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, you are messing `php` and `html` code

```
$arr = array("Apple","orange","strawberry");
$abc = '<table border="2">
            <tr>
                <th>Names</th>
            </tr>';
            foreach($arr as $key){
            $abc.='<tr>
                <td>'.$key.'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
        $abc.='</table>';

echo $abc;
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/lnzLtU)**

Answer (score 0):

You have miss placed the foreach. It is a code block and you have placed it inside the quotes, which will be treated as text. Check the below code.

```
<?php
    $arr = array("Apple","orange","strawberry");
    $abc = '<table border="2"><tr><th>Names</th></tr>';
    foreach($arr as $key){
        $abc .= '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td></tr>';
    }
    $abc .= '</table>';
    echo $abc;
?>
```